# How to transform an arrary of mixed values into a JSON array in an efficient way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

In my scenario, I have the serialized HTML array:

```
[{ name: "Questions[0].ID", value: 1 }, {name: "Questions[0].Answer", value: "Yes"}, { name: "Questions[1].ID", value: 2 }, {name: "Questions[1].Answer", value: "No"}]
```

I need to serialize this HTML form and change its format, because this HTML is in a partial view used in other places where the whole form is posted. But here, I'm only interested in the questions data and need to post that in a specific JSON format.

The JSON structure would be:

```
[{ QuestionID: 1, Answer: "Yes" }, { QuestionID: 2, Answer: "No" }]
```

**Solution 1 - Loop through the array:**

```js
var surveyResponses = [{
  name: "Questions[0].ID",
  value: 1
}, {
  name: "Questions[0].Answer",
  value: "Yes"
}, {
  name: "Questions[1].ID",
  value: 2
}, {
  name: "Questions[1].Answer",
  value: "No"
}];
var responsesList = new Array();
if (surveyResponses != null && surveyResponses.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < surveyResponses.length; i++) {
    var answer = surveyResponses[i++].value;
    var questionID = surveyResponses[i].value;
    responsesList.push({
      QuestionID: questionID,
      Answer: answer
    });
  }
}
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(responsesList) + "</pre>")
```

**Solution 2 - Grep + Map:**

```
var surveyResponses = $("#QuestionsDiv").serializeArray();
var offset = 0;
var responsesList = $.grep(surveyResponses,
    function (answer) {
        return answer.name.indexOf("Answer") > -1;
    }).map(function (answer, i) {
        return { QuestionID: surveyResponses[i + (++offset)].value, Answer: answer.value };
    });
```

So far, I came up with these two solutions. I particularly prefer *Solution 2*, although, the code readability is not the best.

Are there any other (better) ways of doing this conversion? Specially without looping through the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce);

```
var out = arr.reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
  if (i === 0 || i % 2 === 0) {
    p.push({ QuestionID: a[i].value, Answer: a[i + 1].value });
  }
  return p;
}, []);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7cyd842o/)

This will, however, hit each array element. I'm not sure why you're averse to looping but this is by far the easiest method, and will only hit every other element.

```
for (var out = [], i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i+=2) {
  out.push({ QuestionID: arr[i].value, Answer: arr[i + 1].value });
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4dpyzguL/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I like how simple these are.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

Not sure if it is better, but an alternate approach.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Questions[0].ID", value: 1 }, {name: "Questions[0].Answer", value: "Yes"}, { name: "Questions[1].ID", value: 2 }, {name: "Questions[1].Answer", value: "No"}];

var _tmp = {};
data.forEach(function(item){
  var k = item.name.split(".");
  if(!_tmp[k[0]])
    _tmp[k[0]] = {}
  
    if(k[1]==="ID")
      k[1] = "QuestionID"
  _tmp[k[0]][k[1]] = item.value;
});

var result = Object.keys(_tmp).map(function(k){return _tmp[k]});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,2) + "</pre>")
```